# How delete the last page in vba word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word file with table object.

In my script I copy and paste many times and as a result pages are added.

Copy and paste:

```
Dim Range2 As Range
Dim r
i_TableAsRange.Copy
Set Range2 = ActiveDocument.Content
Range2.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
Range2.Paste
```

I want to delete all pages after the second page.

How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is too vague. Show the code and the results.

Comment: i edit my question  with example code that i used to copy

Comment: See what to do when some answer your question - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289619

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from Marvin_Guo's post [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b5b34fd3-e36b-432c-94d2-9c687e273440/how-do-i-delete-a-range-pages-in-a-document-using-vba?forum=worddev)

```
Sub DeleteAfterPageTwo()

Dim rng As Range
Dim pageCount As Integer

' work out how many pages
pageCount = ActiveDocument.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)

' set a range from page 3 to the end
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=3
Set rng = Selection.Range
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=pageCount
rng.End = Selection.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.End

' delete the range
rng.Delete

' optionally remove the left over blank page
Selection.TypeBackspace
Selection.TypeBackspace

End Sub
```

Comment: When I copied and pasted a table object, it was added to the end of the existing table.
The solution was to delete rows up to the line I wanted to leave and this caused the generated pages to be deleted.