# how to get the word last para and add line and put to the last page bottom

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is there a way to add a line before and after the last pare.
get zhe last para in the bottom of the last page.
just like follow

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. [image]

Comment: Yes, there is a way. But I think You should know that SO is not wishing well and You are supposed to show some engagement to your question :)

Comment: I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: Here You can find sth about last page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43703811/how-delete-the-last-page-in-vba-word

Comment: You do not need to search the net. All the research tools you need are in Word. You cannot successfully automate Word using VBA unless you know how to perform the required actions in the UI. So first, learn how to add lines above and below a paragraph using the Word UI. Second, record a macro of those actions. Third, use the Object Browser to learn more about the objects. (Hint: look up Paragraphs)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim shape, l1 as shape, rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Last.Range
    Set shape = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddCanvas(20, 20, CentimetersToPoints(15.6), CentimetersToPoints(1), rng)
    Set lineT1 = shape.CanvasItems.AddLine(0, 0, CentimetersToPoints(15.6), 0)
        With lineT1.Line
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .Weight = CentimetersToPoints(0.05)
        End With
```